# Track changes by JQuery on the Input Component

Tags: jquery

I am trying to track changes on input element below element.

```
<input type="text" id="amount" style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;">
```

This is working when I changed input values manually

```
$( "input[type='text']" ).change(function() {
    alert( "Test" );
  });
```

But when I add `readonly` parameter to input value and change input values via Jquery it does not working anymore? How can track changes handled by JQuery?

```
<input type="text" id="amount" readonly style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;">
```

=============================
Thanks to
Neeraj Amoli
Pranav C Balan

Solution:

Html

```
<input type="text" id="amount" readonly style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;">
```

JQuery

```
$("#amount").val("Something").trigger('change');

$("#amount").change(function () {
    console.log("Test");
    });
```

Comment: you have  to trigger change event programatically... use `.change()` or `.trigger('change')`

Comment: Thank you this solved my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#amount").on('change',function() {
   alert("Test" );
   console.log($(this).val());
});
```